# Why does an image embed successfully in an email with .Display but not .Send?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, ms-office

This is something that I'm finding very weird and hard to solve, I have the following code:

```
Sub EmailImage()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As MailItem
Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\User1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")
oEmail.Close olSave
oEmail.To = "abc@abc123.com"
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:thumbs-up.jpg' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
oEmail.Display
Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

With the `.Display` code the image embeds successfully and once the image displays and you click send the reciever can see the image in the email, as below:

[image]

But the problem is I have a lot of emails to send, so it would be more appropriate to use `.Send` rather than `.Display`, once I do this however the image gets attached to the email but cannot be seen in it.

Here's the changed code:

```
Sub EmailImage()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As MailItem
Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\User1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")
oEmail.Close olSave
oEmail.To = "abc@abc123.com"
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:thumbs-up.jpg' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
oEmail.Send
Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

And an image of what can be seen in the email:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening, can someone please help?

Please note, I am using Windows 7, Excel 2010, and Outlook 2010.

Comment: Hmm... the modified version worked for me. I was testing in Outlook/Excel 2013, not sure if that made a difference. Also, I was getting a `User-defined type not defined` error, so I switched the first two lines for `Dim oApp As Object` and `Dim oEmail As Object` and didn't bother with the next two Dims. But I don't think that is the root cause of your issue here.

Comment: If I were you I would put that as an answer, don't understand what difference that made at all but it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Nice, glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property (DASL name http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F) on the attachment to the value matching the `cid` attribute of the `img` tag in the HTML body.

```
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\User1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")
oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid"
...
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:MyCid' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
```

Comment: I don't understand why it would work with .Display in this way and not .Send, and why the other answer seems to work but you're saying that I need to set the property. What does setting this property do?

Comment: When you touch Outlook inspector (through Display, Close, GetInspector), Outlook runs extra code that validates your data. You got lucky it was smart enough to fix your attachment. If you do not want to rely on that, set the  PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID  property explicitly - that is how Outlook knows which attachment must be used for a particular img tag.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, apologies for not responding. When I run that code I get the error `Run-time error: 438: Object doesn't support this property or method` do you know why this would appear and how to resolve it?

Comment: It looks like I has PropertyAccessor with a single "s". Try the updated code above.

Comment: `Sub EmailImage()
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oEmail As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\fix1sb1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")
oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid")
oEmail.To = "abc@abc123.com"
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:MyCid' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
oEmail.Send
Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub`

Comment: Hi, this still isn't working, I've been getting some error messages with your code. I've posted a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213518/vba-why-doesnt-my-image-embed-in-a-html-email

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Sub EmailImage()
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oEmail As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\User1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")
oEmail.Close olSave
oEmail.To = "abc@abc123.com"
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:thumbs-up.jpg' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
oEmail.Send
Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, unfortuneately this is no longer working, please see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213518/vba-why-doesnt-my-image-embed-in-a-html-email

Comment: In your code in the linked question you're no longer using `Dim oApp as Object` and `Dim oEmail as Object`