# Why doesn't my image embed in an HTML email?

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to run code in VBA that will send out HTML emails and am trying to embed an image within the email. I have the following code to do so:

```
Sub EmailImage()

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As MailItem
Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\User1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")
oEmail.Close olSave
oEmail.To = "abc@abc123.com"
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:thumbs-up.jpg' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
oEmail.Send
Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

But what happens is that the image gets attached but there's a box with a red cross in it where the image should be, as is shown in the below image:

[image]

I have tried the following adapton to the code:

```
Sub EmailImage()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As MailItem
Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\User1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")

oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid")

oEmail.Close olSave
oEmail.To = "abc@abc123.com"
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:MyCid' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
oEmail.Send
Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

But this gives me the error "Compile error: expected =" on the line `oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid")` so I tried to take out the `, "MyCid")` and changed the code in the email to just `oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:thumbs-up.jpg' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"` again, so that it looks like this:

```
Sub EmailImage()

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As MailItem
Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\User1\Documents\thumbs-up.jpg")
oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F")

oEmail.Close olSave
oEmail.To = "abc@abc123.com"
oEmail.HTMLBody = "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:thumbs-up.jpg' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
oEmail.Send
Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

But I now get the error `Compile error: argument not optional` with it pointing at the `.SetProperty` part of the line `oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F")`.

Please note that I am using Windows 7, Microsoft Excel 2010 and Microsoft Outlook 2010.

Comment: I think the red X you're seeing is because it can't find the attached/embedded image.  Can you inspect that and see what it's looking for?  I.e., if the HTML is trying to load something that it doesn't have access to, you'll see that box.

Comment: But when I click on the attachment it opens the correct image

Comment: Okay.  So you're properly attaching it.  But you're not properly embedding it.  As I said, inspect the red X.

Comment: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F doesn't point to anything. If you follow the link you get the message *The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after Googling the error message "Compile error: expected =", the changing the line:

```
oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid")
```

To:

```
Call oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid")
```

Worked.

I found this out from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/vba-compile-error-expect-in-sub-call/a47c752f-3034-41a6-a77c-b3ddaa34b24c?auth=1

Thank you for all your comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not like parenthesis when calling a sub - try to get rid  of ():
    oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid"